# Mysql left join returns more than one row

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have 3 tables and some fields' names are the same. Here is the first table named **semp**:

[image]

The second one's name **semp_k**:

[image]

And the third is **semp_y**:

[image]

You see, the main table is the first and the others are related it. The first table has got 3 row. So when I fetch it, it must return 3 row. But when I fetch the first table, it multiples returned rows with sum of second and third table. Here is my code:

```
SELECT s.*, k.*, y.* FROM semp AS s LEFT JOIN semp_k AS k ON s.no = k.semp_no LEFT JOIN semp_y AS y ON s.no = y.semp_no WHERE s.durum = 1 ORDER BY s.bas_t DESC
```

Comment: use **group by s.no**

Comment: Is it simple like this? :) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use MySQL `group by`

```
group by s.no
```

or try this :-

```
SELECT
s.*, k.*, y.*
FROM
semp AS s
LEFT JOIN semp_k AS k ON s. NO = k.semp_no
LEFT JOIN semp_y AS y ON s. NO = y.semp_no
WHERE
s.durum = 1
GROUP BY s.no
ORDER BY
s.bas_t DESC
```

Comment: plz accept my answer if my answer help you :) @Habip OĞUZ

Answer (score 1):

You need to use group by.
Your query should be like this ;

```
SELECT
    s.*, k.*, y.*
FROM
    semp AS s
LEFT JOIN semp_k AS k ON s. NO = k.semp_no
LEFT JOIN semp_y AS y ON s. NO = y.semp_no
WHERE
    s.durum = 1
GROUP BY s.no
ORDER BY
    s.bas_t DESC
```